# Last Active List - VB.NET

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net, time

I've got a client application that's going to update a database every five minutes with the current time, and then I want to output this time as a last active table in a seperate VB application.

I know about mysql time, but I don't quite understand how I can use it to display when a client was last active.

I've looked around and found some stuff about mysql times but I don't fully understand it.

Any help would be great, I'm going to place the results in a ListView with 'Client Name' and 'Last Active' if this helps, and I already know how to connect to my database and retrieve information.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a `DATETIME` for storage. The `TIME` data type is limited to a single "time of day" or a timespan. True, you're looking for the time of day, but to calculate the "Last Active" time you need the date attached. Consider these "Last Active" values (using a 24-hour clock):

- `3/26/2013 at 17:00:00` <-- *this has the maximum time (5PM), but...*
- `3/27/2013 at 08:15:00` <-- *...this is the most recent time because it happens the following day*

In other words, you need the date so you can sort the time.

The MySQL `DATETIME` data type should be supported by VB.NET, but I've never used the two together so I can't guarantee it. To query and report just the time component of the date you have a ton of options. Here are two:

1. Query the entire date/time from MySQL and return it as a `System.DateTime` value to VB.NET. In VB.NET you can format it using `DateTime.ToString` to show only the time components. The MySQL query would go something like this:

   ```
   SELECT ClientName, MAX(LastActive) AS LastActiveDateTime
   FROM your_table
   GROUP BY ClientName
   ```
2. Format the time in MySQL and return it as a `String` to VB.NET. In VB.NET you'll just need to display the string as is. The MySQL query would go something like this:

   ```
   SELECT ClientName, DATE_FORMAT(MAX(LastActive), '%r') AS LastActiveTime
   FROM your_table
   GROUP BY ClientName
   ```

The format code `%r` in the above query will return the time in a 12-hour format with AM/PM, for example `07:55:29 PM`. To return a 24-hour format (`19:55:29`), use `%T` instead.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. In what form do I save the current time to the database?

Comment: No worries. I'm not sure what you mean. If you want to specify the current date and time from VB.NET it's the `DateTime.Now` property. As for working with VB.NET and MySQL in general, there are plenty of tutorials but most of them for some reason show how to connect and that's all. There's one [here](http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlvb/)  - look for the text "insert a new author" to get to the heart of things. You'd use the `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue` method to set your date, with the first argument being the statement's parameter name and the second being `DateTime.Now`.

Comment: DateTime.Now is what I was looking for, I'll give that a try thanks :)